# disable back press only when the application would otherwise go to the background in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, back

My application should ask the user for a confirmation before putting the application in the background when the user presses the back button.

I tried to override `dispatchKeyEvent`. The problem is that I also have fragments that are pushed in the backStack.

I should not ask the confirmation when there is still a fragment in the back stack because in that case the application won't go to the background: it will pop up the fragment from the stack.

Is there a way to distinguish between the case when the application will go to the background and when another fragment will be popped up from the stack in `dispatchKeyEvent`?
If not is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the onBackPressed method and get a list of current tasks from the activity manager and then decide weather to ask the user for conformation or just go back. This solutions is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5975811/328947).

Comment: But fragments are part of the same activity so that method does not work, right? I need something equivalent to that but instead of checking the activities in the task I need to check the fragments in the activity.

Comment: true, another solution could be to track the fragments. I used to track it with a flag, you could possibly do the same and if you flag identifies current UI as the initial fragment the display the dialog.

Comment: right I was trying to check whether there are other solutions. The first fragment in my case is always different so it would be a bit messy to track it

Answer (score 0):

just override onBackPressed.

Also, see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html for better understanding of the notion of backstack in android

Comment: You don't say anything about the problem with the fragments

Comment: thing is, the app stack is getting real complicate these days. your app may not simply be a stack of stuff, but may be intricated with others.

Answer (score 0):

use this method of Activity

```
            @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       // Add here  whatever uoy want

        }
```

Comment: You don't say anything about the problem with the fragments

Answer (score 0):

You can override

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and check for your condition like,

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  if(foo == true)
    showDialog();
  else
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: You don't say anything about the problem with the fragments