# The app sounds media run in the background how to fix it?

Tags: android, flash, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When I exit an application the sound runs on the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652133/when-i-exit-an-application-the-sound-runs-on-the-background)

When i click the home button or back button, the audio/sound still running, the source of the audio is swf(flash) so how can i fix it?

Comment: Did you try to stop whatever it is you want to stop in the `onPause()`?

Comment: how i use onpause()? 
and nope i heard about that... but how i use it? if you can give me the script its will be great! the flash name is: game.swf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pause and release player in `onPause` or `onStop` and init in `onStart` or `onResume`. Android Developer site has [**training**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html) about this. You should add this code in your activity

```
    @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Release the mPlayer because we don't need it when paused
    // and other activities might need to use it.
// You change this part to your implement. Stop your player
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer .release()
            mPlayer = null;
        }
//
}
```

Init again in `onResume`

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Get the mPlayer instance as the activity achieves full user focus
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        initializePlayer (); // Local method to handle mPlayer init
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very mach yuli! but where i need to put this 2 scripts? and i need to edit this 2 codes or just copy and past?

Comment: Paste in your activity and change part which i told in comment. You should see the link i provided. That is the most basic principle for Android developer.

Comment: Thanks but i still not understand... i think i lost...

Comment: Oh thanks! but i get red line error where is the "mPlayer" i need to change the mPlayer to my flash file name?

Comment: Change to which component you use to play your flash file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the onPause method and stop the audio there.

```
player.pause();
```

Comment: X2: how i use onpause()? and nope i heard about that... but how i use it? if you can give me the script its will be great! the flash name is: game.swf

Comment: @GilRalph Check Yul's answer :)

Comment: yep thanks!  but where i need to put this 2 scripts? and i need to edit this 2 codes or just copy and past?

Comment: It's called methods, not scripts ;)
Unless they are overriden the application will have the default behaviour when the application is put into background (onPause is called when that happens). When the application is resumed onResume is called. So in order to make your own application behaviour on a customized way when this actions is called you paste in the override public onPause() and override public onResume() methods in the same class as your activity (I guess you only have one activity). Hence, in the same file where it stands "extends Activity".
Did this make things anymore clear?