# The app sounds still running in the background when click home button how to fix it?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When I exit an application the sound runs on the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652133/when-i-exit-an-application-the-sound-runs-on-the-background)

When i click the home button or back button, the audio/sound still running, the source of the audio is swf(flash) so how can i fix it? i heard something like onpause or something like that...

Comment: Hmm, you are asking the same question 5th time - it won't help you, believe me. Also, this is a very basic question, you should probably start reading Android docs.

Comment: I know... i try again and again like 6 hours! to try understand all the guides over about activity... but i don't understand nothing from this. i spend 6 hours + - to understand something from all the guides but i get errors... and cant understand.( i think i cant understand because they talk about music files and i talk about swf..

Comment: Do you mean that you have a Flash file inside of a `WebView`? In that case, see [How do I pause Flash content in an Android WebView when my activity isn't visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3431351/687315).

Comment: Yep!!!! men thanks a lot! Thanks a lot men!

Answer (score 0):

You heard right :-) The Activity class provides on `onPause()` method, which is called as soon as your Activity is paused, which is the case when it's no longer visible. So you could just overwrite `onPause()` and pause your sound. To resume it when the Activity becomes visible again, overwite `onResume()`. Also have a look at the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), which every Android developer should know be heart.

Comment: Actually, for knowing it by heart, you should suggest `onStop()` instead. "The visible lifetime of an activity happens between a call to `onStart()` until a corresponding call to `onStop()`". Don't pause the audio in `onPause()` because the application is still visible (e.g., a dialog is present)... unless that's really what you want.

Comment: i try it thanks! the problem i need it for swf(flash) file... and i think its little different from other media file.