# Android launch application from notification With Marmalade SDK

Tags: marmalade-edk

im trying to launch application form notification using Android Edk. I succeded to display notification. But i want to launch my application from notification and i can`t make it work. 
Notification is received when application is not running, is triggered from a broadCast reciever.
I think my problem  is related to the activity that i created from notification intent.

Here the notification function:

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, TaskManagerActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( context, 0, resultIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context )
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_day)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
manager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

And here is my activity class:

public class TaskManagerActivity extends Activity
{

```
public static TaskManagerActivity m_Activity;
private static final String TAG = "TaskManagerActivity";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //   setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
```

}

Comment: I added this new activity to manifest xml file, but nothing works when i click on notification.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse) of Android about notification. Also I'd suggest you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification) post of SO.

Comment: https://devnet.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/16205/launch-application-from-notification-android-edk.html