# send data from a broadcast to an activity . how to do send?

Tags: android, android-activity, sms, broadcastreceiver

how to send data from a **broadcatReceiver** to an activity in android as saying catch the **received SMS** and send the SMS (is the data) to the activity its my first time that i work with **broadcatReceiver**  so can anyone help me i will appreciate any help.

i read several tutorials about the data transferring  that have some steps :

- create a class that extends activity
- create a class that extends broadcastReceiver

but i did not know how is  the communication between these 2 classes.

Comment: +1 from my side to yours qustion, i do not know who gave -1...it is a good question

Comment: @ Arman i did create the sms Receive that extends BroadcatsReceiver  with putting intent in the onreceive()  and create activity that must get the intent from the broadcastReciver but it did not workkkk it give empty after i call the key to get the value in the intent

Comment: this question is not clear. starting an activity with parameter is one of the first topics in the android documentation. what have you tried? (i.e. post code, don't just say `it did not work`, as this is not a usable piece of information)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity
{

  private Handler handler = null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.main_layout);

    this.handler = new Handler() {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg)
      {
        SmsMessage sms = (SmsMessage) msg.obj;
        String senderNumber = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
      }
    };

    // Register a new receiver that will trigger on SMS_RECEIVED event
    IntentFiler filer = new IntentFilert("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mSmsReceiver, filter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Unregister the receiver
    unregisterReceiver(mSmsReceiver);
  }

  private mSmsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
      if (bundle == null || bundle.containsKey("pdus") return;

      // Decode the message
      SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

      // Notify the activity with the message
      Message msg = new Message;
      msg.obj = sms;
      YourActivity.this.handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `receiver` and the `Activity` are separate entities and do not usually interact directly. Imagine the following scenario: you have a receiver getting lots of SMS messages, and every time you get one, you launch an `Activity` to show the message received. Wouldn't this be very annoying to the user?

I'd says that you can interact with the user by creating a `Notification` and if the user clicks on it, then you open the `Activity` you want to show the details.

As how to pass the data to the `Activity` (hopefully using a notification first), given that SMS messages are short in nature you can just put the data in the `Intent`.

How to set a `Notification` to launch an `Activity`: see [Open application after clicking on Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification)

Comment: @ s1m3n what i need from the receiving sms is that after i catch the sms i will forward this sms to my email where the email piece is the code of the class that extend activity... so my problem is after getting the received sms i need to send this received sms from the broadcats to the activity

Comment: Now I don't understand:
- Can you explain "the email piece is the code of the class that extend activity"?

Comment: i mean the class that extend Activity is the email code i ... the code of the send email using gmail sender is work  so what i need is that to send the received sms to the email activity and then forward it to email (as a backup )