# How to find notification ID of whatsapp

Tags: android, android-layout, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I would like to keep the notification **ON** from the settings, and want to clear notification of Whatsapp **after 2 min** of receiving. I searched it online where I found out how to remove notification [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs0r4.png). **ClearAll** and clear via **notification ID** was described, but I do not know ***how to find the ID***.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615241/in-android-how-can-i-know-the-current-notification-id-to-clear-the-notification

Comment: I want to find notification id of WhatsApp not my app

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075189/i-want-to-hide-all-notifications-of-other-apps-when-my-android-app-is-in-foregro/51272687#51272687

Just instead of cancelling every notification you need to cancel whatsapp ones so

in onNotificationPosted use


        if(sbm.getPackageName().equals("com.whatsapp")) 
             cancelNotification(sbm.getKey());

instead of cancelAllNotifications as in previous answer

Answer (score 0):

Why did you post screenshot of documentation?

And it's not as simple as you think - notification ID is package specific, which means `NotificationManager.cancel(id)` and `NotificationManager.cancelAll()` only affect notifications posted by your app.

If you want to cancel other applications notifications you need to write your own [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService). Additionally user will need to manually grant notification access for your app in system settings.

Comment: Yes, I've made NotificationListenerService class and instructed user to manually grant notification access to my app. Now if I want to dismiss Whatsapp notification, how can I do it?? Thanks in advance

Comment: @RahulAgrawal You need to use `NotificationListenerService.getActiveNotifications()` then filter through them to find the one coming from your desired package.