# How to make a DownloadManager with pause/resume and progress in notification

Tags: android, download-manager, notification-bar

"Activity A" send url and file name to DownloadManager that start download and show progress in notification, when progress notification is clicked open "Activity B" with list of downloads with all downloads in progress and finished.

Sorry my english

Answer (score 1):

> "Activity A" send url and file name to DownloadManager that start download

`DownloadManager` should be a `Service` because you want it to work in a background and not interact with UI changes such as screen rotation and so on. Implement your own threading inside this `Service` as you need. 
I recommend `ThreadPoolExecutor`. It will allow you to set the number of threads, so you will be able to switch execution from serial to parallel and so on.

> and show progress in notification

Use `startForeground` method call for that. Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

> when progress notification is clicked open "Activity B" with list of downloads with all downloads in progress and finished.

Use `PendingIntent` for that because notifications run in a system process, not in you application process. `PendingIntent` will give you permissions to open `ActivityB`. Refer: [Open application after clicking on Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification)

If you want to show the status of operations in your `ActivityB` you can easily `bind` to your `DownloadManager` and update activity UI via callback from progress updates.