# Android notifications to the notification bar in kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy, pyjnius

I want to create a notification on android in the notification bar. When i click on the notification i want to open my kivy application. The notification should be made from a background service.

How can i do that in kivy?
I would prefer pyjnius and java but plyer is ok.

Comment: This should be of assistance https://github.com/tshirtman/kivy_service_osc I recently did this myself. Only problem is, the notification won't go away. I haven't figured out how to start services that don't generate notifications. I am not sure that it is possible :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but this wasn't basically easily feasible in Kivy up until now. You had to extend the feature using [pyjnius](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius) and implement it yourself, for instance [see how they do in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification).

So I've recently implemented that feature in upstream. I don't know much about Android, so I used the StackOverflow answer linked and other resources.
If you're curious how it got implemented, see my pull request [kivy/plyer#422](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/pull/422).