# onnewIntent method is not called when using Parse.com push notification

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Hi I am developing an android app to receive the push notification from parse.com with below requirement .

application have two activity say A and B.
when i launch my application activity A will be displayed and then activity B when i click button on activity A.

I want to open activity B when i receive push notification message and display on it whether my app running in background or not.

if running on background/or not how can i do that in both the cases.

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open application after clicking on Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification)

Answer (score 0):

Method `onNewIntent()` will be called is case:

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in   their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity().
>   In either case, when the   activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead   of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be   called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to   re-launch it.

If instance of your activity B isn't exist then `onCreate()` will be called.