# Open an image when Push Notification is clicked

Tags: android, push-notification

I've used push notification in my App which fires perfectly and opens my Application when clicked on it. But I want to change its action when clicked. Want I want is, suppose your friend changed his picture or added any pic in her profile then you get a notification, when you click on that notification you got to see the picture he added instead of his profile. I want this kind of functionality, when I get a notification, I want to open that image not my App. How can I do this?

Comment: Hope below link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification

Comment: @Nag I am able to open the home screen of my App. But I want to open an image of an App when I get a notification, which happens in facebook..

Answer (score 0):

Where you build your notification add the some `intent.putExtra` and add the image `uri` which you want to open and next in your `activity` open that image.