# GCM launch background/closed app when get notification (Android)

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with GCM. 
I created a server side notification pusher (in PHP), that send to specific user  (based on location) who have the app, a notification.

I have three class for managing the registration and the notification listener.

```
public class PusherIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {
    private static final String TAG = "PUSHER_ID_LISTENER_SERVICE";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

---

Now the registration class

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "REGISTRATION_SERVICE";

    private int idClient;

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        this.idClient = intent.getIntExtra("idClient", 0);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

        double lat = 0;
        double lon = 0;
        if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
            lat = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
            lon = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Position not available, updating next time.");
        }

        try {
            synchronized (TAG) {
                InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
                String senderId = getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId);
                String token = instanceID.getToken(senderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

                this.sendRegistrationToServer(token, lat, lon);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
        }

        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(this, ActStartPage.class);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token, double lat, double lon) {
        // doing some stuff
    }
}
```

---

And now the Listener

```
public class PusherListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    private static final String TAG = "PUSHER_LISTENER_SERVICE";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("body");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        sendNotification(title, message);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActStartPage.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("menuTabId", 3);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.cancelAll();
        notificationManager.notify((int)(Math.random()), notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

---

My manifest look like this

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="clab.kalitys.mobile.CoreModuleManager.Pusher.PusherListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="clab.kalitys.mobile.CoreModuleManager.Pusher.PusherIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="clab.kalitys.mobile.CoreModuleManager.Pusher.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

---

And finally i launch all that in my main activity in the onCreate

```
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra("idClient", Integer.parseInt(this.getResources().getString(R.string.clientId)));
        startService(intent);
    }
```

---

So now, what is working :

- launch registration : OK
- send notification when app is on foreground or background or removed from current apps : OK
- Click on the notification and launch the app again when the app is on foreground : OK

***What's not working =( :***

- Click on the notification and **launch the app (again)** when the app is in background or removed from current apps

I tried some things, but nothing worked. I don't really good understand the xml settings too.

Here is an example of the JSON i send to gcm :

```
"notification":{
    "body":"blabla",
    "title":"one title"
    "icon":"notification_icon"
},
"data":{
    "body":"blabla",
    "title":"one title"
},
"registration_ids":["id1", "id2", etc]
```

**So what is wrong in my code (or what must i add) for launching the app again when i receive a notification when the app is closed ?**

Any ideas ?

Thanks =)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification

Comment: I looked at you're link, it doesn't help me more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

I just fixed the problem.

The JSON i send is like :

```
"notification":{
    "body":"blabla",
    "title":"one title"
    "icon":"notification_icon"
},
"data":{
    "body":"blabla",
    "title":"one title"
},
"registration_ids":["id1", "id2", etc]
```

---

But this part (from the JSON) :

```
"notification":{
    "body":"blabla",
    "title":"one title"
    "icon":"notification_icon"
}
```

was the problem.

I thought the JSONmessage is in two part, "data" when app is open, and "notification" when app is closed or in background.
<s>I thought that, because the app is closed, how can android know that he must show a notification ? So it's why use "notification" for specify that android must show a notification.</s>

But no, "notification" is used for send simple notification without action.

**So i resolve the problem by sending this JSON :**

```
"data":{
    "body":"blabla",
    "title":"one title"
},
"registration_ids":["id1", "id2", etc]
```