# My Android App starts automatically

Tags: android, restart

EDIT: found out its a problem with my messagereceiving service for push notifications. if i stop service on closing the app the problem doesn't appear anymore but if i click on the received notification in my phone, it starts my app from the wrong activity...
in my messagereceivingservice.java i do

```
    postNotification(new Intent(context, NotificationsActivity.class), context);
```

so is this the issue?

I am doing an app in android where users can create their own profile to interact with their friends.The app includes google maps and push notifications are implemented. 
I can't find out since when this happens but for a while now the app restarts automatically after a while if the user stops or closes the app. 
since i can't post all of my code here, Did anyone come across this problem and has an idea where to search for the source of this problem? may be any service running when app is closed that forces app to restart? i must say i am pretty desperate because the app itself runs perfectly apart from this problem.

at least here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- GCM -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGING -->
<permission
    android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- if you want to keep processor from sleeping when a message is received -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1496945817221747"
    android:exported="true" />

<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DiscoverActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_discover"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile"
        android:parentActivityName=".ProfileActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ProfileActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <!-- FACEBOOK ACTIVITY -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FriendsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_friends"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notifications"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>

    <!-- GCM -->

    <!-- android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" -->

    <receiver
        android:name=".ExternalReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />

            <category android:name=".androidtest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".LoadImageService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".AddFriendService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".AcceptFriendService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".JoinService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".DeleteService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".EditActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MessageReceivingService"
        android:label=".MessageReceivingService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".AndroidMobilePushApp" />
            <action android:name=".ExternalReceiver" />

            <category android:name=".androidtest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".BasesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bases"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you start activity from services. Maybe when you receive some gcm push

Comment: yes i do. so how can i deal with this? found out its a problem with my messagereceiving service. if i stop service on closing the app the problem doesn't appear anymore but if i click on the received notification in my phone, it starts my app from the wrong activity...

Comment: You can specify activity using PendingIntent. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification
or this http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/notify-user/navigation.html
You can set behaviour of backstack for example

Comment: i do already use pending intent in the postNotification method

Answer (score 0):

this is my MessageReceivingService.java

```
public class MessageReceivingService extends Service {
private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
public static SharedPreferences savedValues;

public static final String INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE = "GCM";
final String BASE_URL = "http://www.example.com/";

public String myUserId;
public String registeredUserId;
public String token;
public String myToken;
private final String AUTHORIZATION = "AUTHORIZATION";


public static void sendToApp(Bundle extras, Context context) {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent();
    newIntent.setClass(context, MapsActivity.class);
    newIntent.putExtras(extras);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(newIntent);
}


public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    final String preferences = getString(R.string.preferences);
    savedValues = getSharedPreferences(preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // In later versions multi_process is no longer the default
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        savedValues = getSharedPreferences(preferences, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    }
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getBaseContext());

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefMyUserId = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preferences_user_id), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String defaultUserId = getResources().getString(R.string.default_user_id);
    myUserId = sharedPrefMyUserId.getString(getString(R.string.saved_user_id), defaultUserId);

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefRegisteredUserId = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preferences_register_user_id), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String defaultRegisteredUserId = getResources().getString(R.string.default_register_user_id);
    registeredUserId = sharedPrefRegisteredUserId.getString(getString(R.string.saved_register_user_id), defaultRegisteredUserId);

    // Get app authoken and save it in a variable
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_token), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String defaultToken = getResources().getString(R.string.default_auth_token);
    myToken = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.saved_auth_token), defaultToken);


    SharedPreferences savedValues = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if (savedValues.getBoolean(getString(R.string.first_launch), true) || !myUserId.equals(registeredUserId)) {
        register();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorRegisterUserId = sharedPrefMyUserId.edit();
        editorRegisterUserId.putString(getString(R.string.default_register_user_id), myUserId);
        editorRegisterUserId.commit();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedValues.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.first_launch), false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    // Let AndroidMobilePushApp know we have just initialized and there may be stored messages
    sendToApp(new Bundle(), this);
}

protected static void saveToLog(Bundle extras, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedValues.edit();
    String numOfMissedMessages = context.getString(R.string.num_of_missed_messages);
    int linesOfMessageCount = 0;
    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
        String line = String.format("%s=%s", key, extras.getString(key));
        editor.putString("MessageLine" + linesOfMessageCount, line);
        linesOfMessageCount++;
    }
    editor.putInt(context.getString(R.string.lines_of_message_count), linesOfMessageCount);
    editor.putInt(context.getString(R.string.lines_of_message_count), linesOfMessageCount);
    editor.putInt(numOfMissedMessages, savedValues.getInt(numOfMissedMessages, 0) + 1);
    editor.commit();
    //postNotification(new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class), context);
    postNotification(new Intent(context, NotificationsActivity.class), context);
}

protected static void postNotification(Intent intentAction, Context context) {
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    int numOfMissedMessages = 0;
    String missedMessage = "";
    if(savedValues != null){
        missedMessage = savedValues.getString("MessageLine2", "nothing there");
    }

    Log.v("NUMOFMISSEDMESSAGES", String.valueOf(numOfMissedMessages));

    final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(missedMessage.substring(missedMessage.indexOf("=") + 1, missedMessage.length()))
            .setContentText("")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();


    mNotificationManager.notify(R.string.notification_number, notification);
}

private void register() {
    new AsyncTask() {
        protected Object doInBackground(final Object... params) {

            try {
                String instanceId = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getId();
                //token = gcm.register(getString(R.string.project_number));
                token = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getToken(getString(R.string.project_number), INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
                Log.i("registrationId", token);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("Registration Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            new SendRegUserId().execute();
        }
    }.execute();


}

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

/* Class to register new user */

public class SendRegUserId extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = SendRegUserId.class.getSimpleName();

    String id;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.v("MYSENDTOKEN", token);

        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String jsonStr = null;

        try {
            String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8");
            Log.v("ENCODEDTOKEN", encoded);
            String sendDataUrl = BASE_URL + "messages/adddevicetoaws/" + URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8") + "/android";


            URL url = new URL(sendDataUrl);

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty(AUTHORIZATION, myToken);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                //jsonStr = null;
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                jsonStr = null;
                return null;
            }
            jsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ProfileFragment", "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the data, there's no point in attempting
            // to parse it.
            jsonStr = null;
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("ProfileFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        Log.v("JSONSTR", jsonStr);
        return jsonStr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result != null) {

        }
    }
}
```

}