# Launch Activity when notification is clicked

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to open an Activity when I click on the notification from the Status bar. I have seen this answered on StackOverflow but none of these answers work for me. This is my code:

```
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_file_cloud_upload);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_upload_title));

    //when this notification is clicked and the upload is running, open the upload fragment
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);

    this.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID_UPLOADING_PROGRESS, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.android.app.MainActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_short_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13716784/776244

Comment: Why are you using `this.startForeground` instead of `NotificationManager.notify`?

Comment: What happens when you click on the notification?

Comment: @Malith Lakshan, the status bar is closed and nothing more happens.

Comment: @Samir Mangroliya, this solution does not work for me, I am using NotificationCompat, and this answer is for Notification.

Comment: @jaibatrik, this is neccesary because of the app workflow

Comment: Check if the context provided to the Pending intent is correct or not,try to use ClassName.this, if it is from a service or an activity

Comment: Is this the only notification you post from the Service? Anyway,Change pending intent request code to another number and see if the behavior is same.

Comment: Yep, I have tried with diferents intents request codes  and it is the same behavior

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have realized that I have to write this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity_.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

Thanks a lot for all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need all this flags and configurations just to open an activity from the PendingIntent. You certainly don't need

```
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
```

Remove them and try again.

Furthermore: is the package name of the MainActivity as intended (**com.android.app.MainActivity**)?

Answer (score 0):

try below solution hope it works for you

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourActivity....class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent blogIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, INT CONSTANTS, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

From Notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
.
.
.
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(blogIntent);


Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_NEW_BLOG, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add custom receiver in manifest

```
       <receiver
            android:name=".IntentReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- add notification action here  -->

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In Intent receiver class override on recieve method

```
public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //call your activity here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried and it didnt work. This onReceived method is not called

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code

/* Invoking the default notification service */
        NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Test");
        mBuilder.setContentText(text2);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);

   /* Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app */
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationListActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationListActivity.class);

   /* Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack */
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   /* notificationID allows you to update the notification later on. */
        mNotificationManager.notify(9999, mBuilder.build());
```