# How can i open Activity when notification click

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I need use notification with click event, i have notification method but this method don't open my activity.

My code:

```
 private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("EXX")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg)          
        .setOngoing(true);          
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

is this possible,

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open application after clicking on Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification)

Comment: Not a duplicate. OP is just missing the `setContentIntent()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Change Your method, like that;

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("yourpackage.notifyId", NOTIFICATION_ID);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("EXX")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(msg))
            .addAction(getNotificationIcon(), "Action Button", pIntent)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setOngoing(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

and add your mainactivity

```
    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

this code working.

Comment: oh thanks ! this code working on me ! i love you bro <3

Comment: Please be aware that `addAction(getNotificationIcon(), "Action Button", pIntent)` is deprecated

Answer (score 7):

Hey @John it's very simple

you just have to do

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
```

...
// Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's
// no need to create an artificial back stack.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApp())
            .addNextIntent(intent)
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And set pending Intent in mBuilder

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("EXX")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg)          
        .setOngoing(true);    
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

and you done :)

Comment: In place of `getApp()` could use `MainActivity.class` or the specific activity name to specify the name of your activity.