# How to start Flutter application from foreground service

Tags: java, android, flutter, service

I have a Flutter app, which runs a never ending foreground service and it is defined like this:

```
    private void startForeground() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
            NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("service")
            .setContentText("Service is running background")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build());
}
```

and I start service like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smile)
            .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();
    startForeground(2, notification);
```

My foreground service is showing notification all the time.

Is it possible to start a Flutter app when user press on notification which is showed by foreground service, even if the Flutter app isn't running in background? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To launch an `Activity` when clicking on a notification, you can use the `PendingIntent`. You already have this implemented in the first sample, but here are some links. [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#java) [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026431/how-can-i-open-activity-when-notification-click)

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks. But what about Flutter app, how can I start it?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I understand you. I need to start MainActivity, which extends FlutterActivity..