# Android: What code do I use to launch saved data from MainActivity.java to it's own informational page?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For the app I am building it will randomly select a restaurant (randomResturantName) from my array and print it with toast.

How would I make it so that the user can click on the popup to go to another java page where I will have the chosen restaurant name and other info?

[What my toast prints out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfwfK.png)

My code:

```
    private void pickRestaurant(int checkedRadioButtonId) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomNumber = -1;

    switch (checkedRadioButtonId) {
        case R.id.Asian:
            randomNumber = r.nextInt(6-1)+1 ;
            //1-6

            break;
        case R.id.middle_eastern:
            randomNumber = r.nextInt(9-7) +7  ;
            break;

        case R.id.Pizza:
            randomNumber = r.nextInt(11) + 6;
            break;

    }

    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "Random number to pick restaurant is: " + randomNumber);

    String randomRestaurantName = resArray.get(randomNumber).getName();
    Toast toast = null;

    if (randomNumber < 0) {
        toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Select from one of the following:",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    } else {
        toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Today you will eat at "
                + randomRestaurantName , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,chaCha.class);
    intent.putExtra("KEY",randomRestaurantName);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

chaCha.java

```
public class chaCha {

private Intent getIntent;
Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras();
String randomRestaurantName = bundle.getString("KEY");
```

}

Comment: if you would like user to interact with the message, then you should not show the message using toast, but instead of a dialog (e.g.alertdialog).

Comment: From your discussion below, I recommend you to take a free course that will help you start Android App Development from [New Boston](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=6) and if you are really interested in developing Android apps, you can follow [Udacity's Android Beginner's course designed by Google.](https://cn.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837) (also free).

Answer (score 0):

make intent and pass the data along it like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisClass.this,NextClass.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY",RestaurentName);
startActivity(intent);
```

in next class recieve intent and get extras like:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras();
String RestaurentName = bundle.getString("KEY");
```

Comment: it just says "Food selector has stopped"

Comment: currently my main is already extended  "public class MainActivity extends Activity  {"

Comment: check this

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignupActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY","slkjf");
        startActivity(intent);

now in next activity 
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String s = b.getString("KEY");

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {edu.temple.tuyen.templefoodselector/edu.temple.tuyen.templefoodselector.chaCha}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to Android Studios

Comment: have you declared your next activity in the AndroidManifest.xml????
like: <activity android:name=".YourActivityName"/>

Answer (score 0):

Use `Notifications`, you can not interact with `Toast`. Then set `Intent` (wrapped in `PendingIntent`) to that `Notification` object, and pass Restaurant name and other info in Intent extras.

Building a notification is as simple as (from [Google Dev Site](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#action)):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon) // set icon
    .setContentTitle("Random Restaurant")
    .setContentText(randomRestaurantName);

NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds the notification and issues it.
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

How to handle click on notification, here SO has [already an answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification)

You can also use `Dialog` but you will have to write more code and handle more stuffs like, listeners to `Dialog` button, or in case of custom `Dialog`, layouts etc. Here is official tutorial doc for [`Dialogs`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

*Reposting my comment to emphasize the advice:*

From your discussion above, I recommend you to take a free course that will help you start Android App Development from [New Boston](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=6) and if you are really interested in developing Android apps, you can follow [Udacity's Android Beginner's course designed by Google.](https://cn.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837) (also free).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot click on Toast message.
Better use POPUP on click of radio button instead of TOAST.