# MediaStyleNotification: Play/Pause button does not respond to click

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, mediabrowserservice

In my app when the user chooses an audio file for playing, when the file is ready and the playback starts a MediaStyle Notification is shown successfully.

The metadata info is updated, title, icon etc. But…

```
1.Play/Pause button does not respond to clicks.
2.Clicking the notification does not open the activity.
3.Swipe gesture triggers also… nothing
```

[image]

I don’t know what I am missing. You can have a look at my [MediaBrowserService](https://github.com/tomasmichael995/GreekPodcasts_2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/gr/kalymnos/sk3m3l10/greekpodcasts/playback_service/PlaybackService.java) class.

Comment: Having a quick look it seems that your class doesn't follow the same layout as [this](http://sapandiwakar.in/android-media-player-lock-screen/). There is also another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification) that explains how to open an intent from a notification.

Comment: You're right @WoodyDev, it does not follow the layout you proposed. But I believe it does follow the layout from the official docs -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice#mediastyle-notifications.

Comment: Have you tried this on the most recent version of the code? The play/pause button in the notification is working fine for me - Tested on Android 5.1 phone. [On Android 8.0 the notification does not appear for some reason]

Comment: I think you've probably fixed it whilst working on the home screen widget. It is nice that they share most of the same framework in terms of the pending intent handling.

Answer (score 2):

The code being discussed:

```
 private void showMediaStyleNotification() {
        // Given a media session and its context (usually the component containing the session)
        // Create a NotificationCompat.Builder

        // Get the session's metadata
        MediaControllerCompat controller = session.getController();
        MediaMetadataCompat mediaMetadata = controller.getMetadata();
        MediaDescriptionCompat description = mediaMetadata.getDescription();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Add the metadata for the currently playing track
        builder
                .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
                .setContentText(description.getSubtitle())
                .setSubText(description.getDescription())
                .setLargeIcon(description.getIconBitmap())

                // Enable launching the player by clicking the notification
                .setContentIntent(controller.getSessionActivity())

                // Stop the service when the notification is swiped away
                .setDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this,
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP))

                // Make the transport controls visible on the lockscreen
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)

                // Add an app icon and set its accent color
                // Be careful about the color
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_headset_pink_40dp)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.secondaryColor))

                // Add a pause button
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.drawable.ic_pause_white_40dp, getString(R.string.pause_label),
                        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)))

                // Take advantage of MediaStyle features
                .setStyle(new MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(session.getSessionToken())
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0)

                        // Add a cancel button
                        .setShowCancelButton(true)
                        .setCancelButtonIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP)));

// Display the notification and place the service in the foreground
        startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID, builder.build());
    }
}
```

initializeMediaSession:

```
stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE);
        session.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build());
```

When I press play/pause it goes into here: getPlaybackStateFromPlayerState. The only problematic thing is that the play/pause button graphic is not updated. It always shows pause...

```
   case STARTED:
        return stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, currentPosition, playbackSpeed)
                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE
                        | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO
                        | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY)
                .build();
    case PAUSED:
        return stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, currentPosition, playbackSpeed)
                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE
                        | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO
                        | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE)
                .build();
```

[image]