# adding logs that Notification's Action was clicked

Tags: android, android-notifications

I would like to add statistics that my Notification's Action was clicked.

I'm using standard `NotificationCompat.Action`.

Can I somehow set click listener to the Notification's Action?

I could pass in PendingIntent the flag and later in my Activity log statistics dependently on the flag, but it's so over engineered.

Comment: You can add onClickListener to notification's action.

Comment: There is no `setOnClickListener` for `NotificationCompat.Action`

Comment: yes there isn't but you can set onClick tasks in onReceive() method of the notification.

Comment: I won't be able to differentiate between actions there. Could you send the link to the code/documentation, what do you mean?

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification. In this way you can add a listener to your notification and on that click you can add logs or do whatever you want to do.

Comment: Sorry @Umair, but it's unrelated. I'm asking about clicking actions in Notification like e.g. "Like" action in Facebook Messanger notification