# how to check if activity is still in the stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

what is the better way to check if the activity is still in the stack in order to call it back ?

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyClass.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Why care? That's up to Android.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975811/how-to-check-if-an-activity-is-the-last-one-in-the-activity-stack-for-an-applica/6242122#6242122

Comment: cos i have an activity who needs params in order to retrieve data from and xml file , so i want call it back from the stack to avoid passing params and gettinig data from the file cos it's gonna be painfull for the user to see everytime the ProgressDialog.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at the [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) API

To get an instance of the ActivityManager use this code:

```
ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
```

Comment: It would be great to have more details on how exactly should I use ActivityManager to check if the activity is on the stack. Just "read documentation of this class" is not good enough IMO.

Comment: He was referring to ActivityManager.getRunningTasks, but it's been deprecated in lollipop.

Answer (score 6):

I am surprised how unpopular this (kind of) question(s) is.

Let me start from the solution first:
Since `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks` is deprecated since API 21,
We have to find another way to get what activities are in the backstack. And I realized that we can actually implement our own "stack"!

I declared an ArrayList in MyOwnApplication:

```
private ArrayList<Class> runningActivities = new ArrayList<>();
```

And added public methods to access and modify this list:

```
public void addThisActivityToRunningActivityies (Class cls) {
    if (!runningActivities.contains(cls)) runningActivities.add(cls);
}

public void removeThisActivityFromRunningActivities (Class cls) {
    if (runningActivities.contains(cls)) runningActivities.remove(cls);
}

public boolean isActivityInBackStack (Class cls) {
    return runningActivities.contains(cls);
}
```

In a `BaseActivity` where all activities extend it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((MyOwnApplication)getApplication()).addThisActivityToRunningActivityies(this.getClass());
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ((MyOwnApplication)getApplication()).removeThisActivityFromRunningActivities(this.getClass());
}
```

And then you can easily use `isActivityInBackStack` to check.

**WHY IS THIS NECESSARY?**

Yes, of course, most cases can be done by using Intent Flags and proper navigation.
But there is such a use case, which I think should be common, that I don't find a solution simply by using intent flags.

Suppose I have an application that has a navigation drawer in almost every activity.
I navigate from `MainActivity` to `ActivityA`, and then created `ChildActivityB` from `ActivityA`. Please note that `ActivityA` is not parent of `ChildActivityB` since `ChildActivityB` can be opened from other activities such as notification.

Note that, `ChildActivityB` also has a drawer. I can navigate to `ActivityA` through drawer, instead of pressing up or back button. Now, imagine you loop through such process: Activity A -> ChildActivity B -> Drawer -> Activity A -> ChildActivityB -> Drawer -> Activity A .....
Infinite activities will be created in the backstack.
To fix such behavior, we need to use Intent Flags:

```
(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

So far so good.
However, I have custom activity transition animations by using `overridePendingTransition()`. I noticed that if I put the above intent flags together with `overridePendingTransition()`, **there will be a glitch in animation because the activity is destroyed at the middle of the animation**, due to the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

Now, if I am able to detect whether `ActivityA` is in the backstack or not, the behavior will be perfect:

```
private void navigateToDrawerItems(Class cls) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, cls);
    if (((MyOwnApplication)getApplication()).isActivityInBackStack(cls)) {
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the navigation use case. I will add that while this is a valid use case for navigation drawer, it's even more important for Tab Bar navigation (aka BottomNavigationView). Android has no FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT for fragment backstack. So if you want to easily keep state while switching between tabs AND not run out of memory, using activity tabs instead of fragment tabs is the only way.

Comment: This stack will contain only the top-most activity after process death (low memory condition) and is therefore unreliable in production code.

Comment: Revisiting after 2 and a half year, I now understand why this kind of question is unpopular. It is because the example I gave above is actually not a good UX. In that example, child B shouldn't be allowed to have a drawer. It should instead can just be closed, something like a pop-up activity (the concept of modal in iOS). If you have the same UX I mentioned, try to persuade your designer.

Comment: But this doesn't deal with multiple instances.  Say A -> B -> C -> A -> C ...  How can I distinguish different instances?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle global variable as indicator inside `onCreate()` and `onDestory()` of specific class, OR inside `onActivityCreated()` and `onActivityDestroyed()` of ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.

e.g.:

```
  registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

      @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          if (activity instanceof YourActivity) {
              myGlobalData.setActExist(true);
          } 
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
          if (activity instanceof YourActivity) {
              myGlobalData.setActExist(false);
          }
      }
  });
```