# Exiting my app programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, exit, android-notifications

How do I exit my app programmatically from within my app? I have an exit button that brings up a dialog prompting the user to confirm exit. The back button does the same thing. This works usually. However, I'm also launching intents back to my MainActivity when I receive certain events, and the user taps on the notifications. I notice that when the intent is launched in this case, and then the user tries to exit, the app does not exit, but rather seems to go back to the previous instance. If I tap on 3 notifications which launches 3 intents back to MainActivity, I realize that I need to exit the app 3 times before it goes back to the homescreen.

Below is my exit code:

```
private AlertDialog alert;
if (alert != null) {
  if (alert.isShowing()) {
   alert.dismiss();
  }
}
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Exit");
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(false);
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    getActivity().finish();
    System.exit(0);
  }
}).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    dialog.cancel();
  }
});
alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Here is my notification/intent code

```
Intent launchIntent;
launchIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
launchIntent.putExtra("myType", type);
launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
  context).setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
  .setContentText(notificationMessage)
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
  .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
  .setAutoCancel(true)
  .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
  .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
notificationManager.notify(notifyId, noti.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First  two consideration:

- Don't use an exit button in your application, and more important don't bother the user with a dialog when he presses back, asking if he want to exit. The android system will take care to shut down your app when the user exit with the back key.
- You don't need to call `System.exit(0)` to terminate an `Activity`, just `Activity.finish()`

To avoid an `Intent` to call multiple instance of the same `Activity` remove the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag from the `Intent` and add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` one.

From Doc:

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
>   If set, and the activity being launched is
>   already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new
>   instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it
>   will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top)
>   old activity as a new Intent.
>
> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.

Comment: I understand the Android guidelines frown upon an exit button, but this is a requirement for my case as my app requires a login, and for security sake, I need to ensure that the app is properly logged out and exited from when the user chooses to exit. I'm terminating the entire app, not just the Activity, which is why I call System.exit(0);

After reading the docs, I changed from FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, and this works on 1 of my devices, but on another device(Samsung S3 with 4.3), I'm still getting the same behavior. Any idea why?

Comment: It's strange, maybe open another question with this subject. For me FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is the right way, I don't know why with S3 doesn't work.

Comment: OK will do. Thanks. Is there any way to view the activity back stack of my app to make sure things are working as they should be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6242122/1080191 This is not exactly what you are asking but maybe can help.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a new Instance of your Activity via using the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. You shouldn't be doing this. You should use your old activity otherwise you keep creating new instances. What is hapepning is each task that you are creating is being added to the ActivityStack and when you hit back it traverses through this list. If you created three instances then it will show your activity 3 times each time you hit back.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed the setFlags line, now the intent flags is 0. However, I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure you should be calling System.exit(0).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your activity as Single instance so that from anywhere you call the device will return the same activity from the stack.

In Manifest.xml

" ...  android:launchMode="singleInstance">

Comment: Hi, just tried this, and yes it works...sorta. Exiting the app works as expected. However, now when I launch the intent from the notification, the activity doesn't get the extras nor action that were put in the notification.