# How to check for existing activities when back button pressed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, stack

Generally, when the back button is clicked, I call `finish()`, and I am taken back to the previous `activity` (which is my MenuActivity) :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finish();

}
```

However, sometimes the there are no other `activities` running when the back button is clicked and the app simply exits. Is there a way I can check if an `activity` exists or is running in the background/in `onPause` state etc...

I would like to write something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(isActivitiesInStack) //if there are still activities in stack

        finish(); //simply call finish and be taken back to next activity

    else { // else, there are no acitivites in the stack

        Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, MenuActivity.class); // then create an intent and send me to the menu acitivy
        startActivity(intent);
        finish()          
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6242122/2715073) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know to which activity you want to go in `onBackPressed()` you can start the activity with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. It would switch to the instance of `MenuActivity` if an instance is existing, but it would also remove all activity instances which are between your current activity instance and the `MenuActivity` instance. In the other case it would just start a new instance.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MenuActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, it may be helpful to you

```
public boolean isRunning(Context ctx) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
        if (ctx.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getPackageName())) 
            return true;                                  
    }

    return false;
}
```

Anyhow this method has been deprecated from Android API 21 (Lollipop)