# How to know which actives are present in xamarin android?? should i use ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.NumActivities

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i want to go particular activity that is already present.
I dont want to call on create of particular activity f it is already present in backstack

and reorder and brought to front is calling on create

Comment: Hey Ayush it is possible to do but for 99% of the cases, if you need it, you are doing something wrong. Android navigation rules suggest using Fragments instead of Activities for navigation. So you can have a LoginActivity and then your UserActivity, but one ends and the other one starts, so you won't even have two. What's the particular use case you need it for?

Comment: If you use `ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.NumActivities`, you can get the count of  activities, you cannot get all of running activities name, if you want to get the all of running acitivities, you should create a list, when a activity was display, then add it, if it executed the finish() method, you can remove this activity from this list.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, it is possible to do but for 99% of the cases, if you need it, you are doing something wrong. Android navigation rules suggest using Fragments instead of Activities for navigation. So you can have a LoginActivity and then your UserActivity, but one ends and the other one starts, so you won't even have two.

I translated the Java code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6222051/11104068) for you, and you can check that thread for a really good description of the same problem from 9 years ago.

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)Application.GetSystemService(ActivityService);

RunningTaskInfo task = manager.GetRunningTasks(10)[0];
System.Console.WriteLine("This is the base activity " + task.BaseActivity.ClassName);
System.Console.WriteLine(task.NumActivities);
System.Console.WriteLine(task.TopActivity);
System.Console.WriteLine(task.Description);
```

PS: You need GET_TASKS if you are supporting a version before Android API 21.