# android- bring a activity to top of stack ONLY IF activity exists on stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities, A - B on back stack, B on top

I knew I could use **FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT** to bring A on top, so that the stack becomes: B - A, A on top

But when there is only one activity, B on the stack: B(no A exists on the stack)

and I found **FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT** will create a new A and so that stack becomes: B - A

how do I have A on top ONLY IF A EXISTED on stack??

and

I wonder if there is any way I could check if A exists on back stack??

Comment: ie, inside Activity-B, you need to know whether Activity-A is there in the back stack or not. If yes, start activity with the FLAG.

Comment: I wonder if there is any way I could check if A exists on back stack

Comment: make activity launch mode to singleTop.

Comment: so if there is no Activity A, what should happen?

Comment: if no A exists, there should be only B on stack


and if A exists, stack1: A - B(B on top) will become stack2: B -A (A on top)

Comment: Hi , this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590581/activities-stack?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

One trick you could do is to keep a static boolean variable in activity `A`. Keep it false by default, make it `true` in `onCreate` of `A` and `false` in `onDestroy` of `A`

In activity `B` check if that value is `true` then launch it otherwise don't.